# How to remove | substract directory name from bash?

Tags: bash

Within my bash script, which is running on a Linux server, I have a variable that points to a specific path, let's call this `my-path`.

```
my-path="/home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1/"
echo "The path is: $my-path"
...
```

From the given variable `my-path`, I am looking for a way only to display the version number `21.1R1`.

The following is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
./script.sh

the path is: /home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1/
the version is: 21.1R1
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "display"? Do you want to edit the variable in place? Do you want the substring to be stored in a separate variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` grouping and back referencing

```
$ sed 's/[^0-9]*\([^/]*\).*/\1/' input_file
21.1R1
```

`/[^0-9]*` - Exclude anything up to the next occurance of a digit character. As this part is not within the parenthesis `()` to be grouped, it will be excluded.

`\([^/]*\)` - This will group everything from the first digit up to the next occurance of `/` slash.

`.*/` - Exclude everything else

`\1` - Return the group with backreference `\1`.

`awk` can also be used.

```
$ awk -F"[/-]" '{print $6}' input_file
21.1R1
```

`-F"[/-]"` - Set delimiter to `/` and `-` then print column 6 which will contain the string.

Answer (score 2):

Bash has a fairly wide variety of built-in mechanisms for manipulating variables' values.  Of particular interest for the present problem are [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) forms that remove prefixes or suffixes that match specified shell patterns.  For example:

```
# Remove any trailing slash and store the result in DIRNAME_NORM
DIRNAME_NORM=${DIRNAME_MAIN%/}

# Emit the value of $DIRNAME_NORM, less the longest prefix matching shell
# pattern *vMX-
echo "${DIRNAME_NORM##*vMX-}"
```

There is no need to rely on an external program for this case.